Autoinstrumention using OTEL collector for .NET framework 4.8 MVC deployed on IIS in Windows x64 not working
Trying auto instrumentation for .NET Framework 4.8 MVC application deployed on IIS Server but there is no metrics or traces generated. Added below environment variable in applicationHost file
   <add name="OneTraffic.Copy" autoStart="true" enable32BitAppOnWin64="false" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" startMode="AlwaysRunning">
       <processModel identityType="SpecificUser" userName="****" password="***" idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
       <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Time, Requests, Schedule, Memory, IsapiUnhealthy, OnDemand, ConfigChange, PrivateMemory">
                <periodicRestart time="00:00:00">
                    <schedule>
                        <add value="04:00:00" />
                    </schedule>
                </periodicRestart>                  
               </recycling>
                <environmentVariables>                  
                <add name  value="OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_LOGS_ENABLED" value="true"/>
                <add name  value="OTEL_SERVICE_NAME" value="COPY"/>
                <add name  value="OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_METRICS_ENABLED" value="true"/>
                <add name  value="OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_INSTRUMENTATION_ENABLED" value="true"/>
                <add name  value="OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_TRACES_ENABLED" value="true"/>
                <add name  value="OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_OPENTRACING_ENABLED" value="true"/>
                <add name  value="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT" value="localhost:4317"/>
                <add name  value="OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL" value="grpc"/>
                <add name  value="OTEL_LOG_LEVEL" value="debug"/>
                </environmentVariables>
        </add>

